# How do I handle promises inside loop inside async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
async func(){
  try{
    let iter=[1,2,3]
    for (i of iter){
      let result=await someFunc()
      pool.query("some query",arrWithResult)
    }
  }catch(err){console.log(err)}
}
```

Here, the loop waits for await. But I don't want that. I need the result and sql query to be executed in sequence but the loop should continue without waiting. I also need value of current i when executing query. Otherwise, I would just push these promises into array and do Promise.all(arr)

```
async func(){
  try{
    let iter=[1,2,3]
    for (i of iter){
      someFunc().then(body=>{pool.query("some query",arrWithResult).catch(err=>err)
    }
  }catch(err){console.log(err)}
}
```

Is this okay? I also thought of making then part async but should I add another try catch block?

So, what is best way for this? Or should i go for then/catch. When doing Promise.all, the value of iter gets lost.

Comment: Which database are you using?  mysql?  Right now, you have a mix of promise and plain callbacks which is unmanageable so we need to get you switch to a promise interface on your database and then we can show you the programming options for sequencing or running parallel.

Comment: Actually, it has promise. The reason I am waiting for then is because  I want contents of for loop to run sequentially. That is it has multiple promises that need to run one after another. But the loop shouldn't wait for await and instead move on to next request. If I just use await, the loop will wait till all await finishes before going to next loop which I don't want.

Comment: You can't have both.  Either your loop pauses so it can sequence the operations to run one after the other in order or it runs them in parallel.  Pick which you want.  And, you didn't answer my question about which exact database driver you were using which is required for me to write a proper answer.

Comment: And, if your REAL problem has three nested loops, then please add your REAL code to the question so we have the ability to offer an answer that applies to the real problem.  You've objected to the existing answers because your question does not disclose the whole problem.  If you show your real code, not some make up pseudo-code, then you will be disclosing the entire problem and people can offer you the best answer that applies to your real problem.  I have no idea why people think they should generalize their question here with pseudo-code, but that is not the way to get the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm underthinking it (or you're overthinking it), but why would you not just refactor into another async function that does what needs to be done on each iteration of the loop, and then `Promise.all()` the list of returned promises to let them resolve?

Something like this:

```js
async func f1() {
 const iter = [ 1, 2, 3 ] ;
 return await Promise.all( iter.map(f2) );
}

async func f2(i) {
 const result = await someFunc() ;
 return await pool.query( "some query" , arrWithResult );
}
```

The the caller then just needs to say ...

````js
const responses = await f1();
```
````

Comment: Maybe I am just overthinking as I am not that skilled in JS. In my code, I have three arrays where I need to have nested values(with around 4-5,4,and 2 elements for three arrays). Then, I have to execute multiple promises and have to create some query and here and there sequentially. The problem is that the nested loop shouldn't wait for the content and instead go to next loop. So, instead of await, I used then catch to have it continue with loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an iterator var for this - this is a job for Array.map()

```
Promise.all([1,2,3].map(i => someFunc().then(body => pool.query("some query",arrWithResult).catch(err=>err));
```

Comment: I actually had to do nested loop for three arrays. So, I didn't use map. Should I use map for three arrays then?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by using three arrays, but yes, probably, map() is still appropriate.  Assuming you mean that your iterator set is something like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]], then you can use map on the inner arrays, inside the callback of a map() call on the top-level array.  Promise.all([...].map(i => Promise.all(i.map(j => someFunc(i, j)))))